# MySQL transaction FOR COMMITING ON TRUE IF

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to make an sql transaction, that only commits the insert if the one date is greater than the other, and rolls back if else..

this is what i have:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO Cene_Prenocevanja VALUES (6, 2, 10.00, 22.39, str_to_date('01-01-1990', '%d-%m-%Y'), str_to_date('01-01-1989', '%d-%m-%Y'));

CREATE VIEW zacasni AS
SELECT Zacetek_Veljavnosti FROM Cene_Prenocevanja WHERE IDCene_Prenocevanja=6
INTO @zacetek;
SELECT Konec_Veljavnosti FROM Cene_Prenocevanja WHERE IDCene_Prenocevanja=6
INTO @konec;

IF @zacetek < @konec THEN
    COMMIT;
ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
END IF;
```

THESE ARE MY RESPONSES...

IF is not valid at this position

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @zacetek < @konec THEN  COMMIT' at line 1

Comment: Simply check the dates **before** the insert and do not insert at all if they don't meet the condition.

Comment: but i need to make it as a transaction in an assingment

Answer (score 0):

Like this? (Comment from  krokodilko)

```
START TRANSACTION;

CREATE VIEW zacasni AS
SELECT Zacetek_Veljavnosti FROM Cene_Prenocevanja WHERE IDCene_Prenocevanja=6
INTO @zacetek;
SELECT Konec_Veljavnosti FROM Cene_Prenocevanja WHERE IDCene_Prenocevanja=6
INTO @konec;

IF @zacetek < @konec THEN
    INSERT INTO Cene_Prenocevanja VALUES (6, 2, 10.00, 22.39, str_to_date('01-01-1990', '%d-%m-%Y'), str_to_date('01-01-1989', '%d-%m-%Y'));
END IF;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL `IF` statement is only allowed in the store procedures. To rollback the transaction you can try to insert an invalid data if your condition is `FALSE`. Let's suppose your `IDCene_Prenocevanja` is defined as `NOT NULL`. Then you can do it this way:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
# Use IF function to set proper value to @id
SELECT @id := (
  SELECT IF(str_to_date('01-01-1990', '%d-%m-%Y') > str_to_date('01-01-1989', '%d-%m-%Y'), 6, NULL)
);
# Use @id in insertion
INSERT INTO Cene_Prenocevanja VALUES (@id, 2, 10.00, 22.39, str_to_date('01-01-1990', '%d-%m-%Y'), str_to_date('01-01-1989', '%d-%m-%Y'));
COMMIT;
```

So if the condition is `FALSE` it tries to insert `NULL` into `NOT NULL` field which rolls the transaction back.